# get file details whenever a file land in s3 bucket & then trigger a glue job for each individual files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, aws-event-bridge

I have a general glue job which will execute based on the file name that is landing in s3 bucket. So right now we are creating an event based trigger which will execute a workflow. (Event is whenever a file land in s3). Is there any way to get the file details like file name or s3 uri and then pass this info to the workflow as a parameter.

Comment: Use lambda as an intermidate step.

Comment: ok.but how can I get the file details if my event will invoke a lambda function

Comment: File details should be in the event payload.

Comment: okay and then how can i use this fiile name as a parameter for my glue job?

Answer (score 3):

> how can i use this fiile name as a parameter for my glue job?

The [AWS docs explain](https://how%20can%20i%20use%20this%20fiile%20name%20as%20a%20parameter%20for%20my%20glue%20job?) how to pass arguments to a glue job and how to read them in the job itself. So basically your lambda would call [start_job_run](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.start_job_run) and pass `Arguments` (e.g. S3 object name) to your job. The job, when started, would read the arguments passed and perform actions based on them.